# Firestore Change Leading To Multiple Firings

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, retrofit

I have a list that is loaded by firestore + retrofit.  It shows chats which are not hidden and hidden.  Whenever I press the button on the recycler view to hide or show, the recycler view loads multiple items which have been removed.  Please help me to make this hide/show function properly so this error of multiple loading in recycler view goes away.  The setup is in a fragment with viewpager.  It might look like a lot of code, but is required to get the answer.  The alternative way is to have two separate lists (one of hidden and one for shown) but I am trying to see if it can be done this way.

**On Fragment Load (Working Fine)**

```
getChatListFromFireBase("0");

// Populate The Visible Chat List On Button Click
    ivShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        getChatListFromFireBase("0");
    }
});

// Populate The Hidden Chat List On Button Click
    ivHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        getChatListFromFireBase("1");
    }
});
```

**Function To Show List in Fragement**

```
// Get Chats List From FireStore
private void getChatListFromFireBase(String hiddenStatus) {

    lIndividualChatList.clear();
    lIndividualChatListIds.clear();

    fbFs.collection("individual_chats").document(mySqlUserId).collection("lists").whereEqualTo("hide_status", hiddenStatus).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e != null) {

            }

            for (DocumentChange dc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                switch (dc.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        key = dc.getDocument().getId();
                        firebaseRetrofitQuery(dc, "Added", key);
                        break;

                    case MODIFIED:
                        key = dc.getDocument().getId();
                        // Do The Change Function
                        firebaseRetrofitQuery(dc, "Changed", key);
                        break;

                    case REMOVED:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Supporting Function In Fragment**

```
// Retrofit Query
private void firebaseRetrofitQuery(DocumentChange documentChange, final String childActivityType, final String key) {

    if (childActivityType.equals("Added")) {
        lIndividualChatListIds.add(key);
    }

    // Get The Receiver Id To Get Data From Other Nodes
    final String mySqlFriendUserId = documentChange.getDocument().getId();
    final String hideStatus = (String) documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("hide_status");

    // Use Retrofit Call
    Call<JsonObject> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().profilesGetApi().getIndividualDetails(mySqlUserId, mySqlFriendUserId);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<JsonObject> call, @NonNull Response<JsonObject> response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                // Check If User Array Has Anything
                JSONArray userArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_array");

                // Get The Json Object
                JSONObject returnJSONObject = userArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String name = returnJSONObject.optString("name");


                if (childActivityType.equals("Added")) {

                    // Populate The Array List With Data From Both Nodes
                    lIndividualChatList.add(new IndividualListModel(name, hideStatus));
                }

                if (childActivityType.equals("Changed")) {

                    int index = lIndividualChatListIds.indexOf(key);
                    lIndividualChatList.set(index, new IndividualListModel(name, hideStatus));
                }

                // Use The Adapter To Populate The Recycler View
                aIndividualChatList = new IndividualListAdapter(getContext(), lIndividualChatList, senderActivity, new IndividualListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClicked(final Map data) {

                    }
                });

                rvList.setAdapter(aIndividualChatList);
                aIndividualChatList.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<JsonObject> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

**In The Recycler View Adapter**

```
viewHolder.ivHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override public void onClick (View v){

    fbFs.collection("individual_chats").document(mySqlUserId).collection("lists").document(individualListModel.getMysql_friend_user_id()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {

                    String hiddenStatus = document.getString("hide_status");

                    if (hiddenStatus.equals("0")) {

                        fbFs.collection("individual_chats").document(mySqlUserId).collection("lists").document(individualListModel.getMysql_friend_user_id()).update("hide_status", "1");

                    }

                    if (hiddenStatus.equals("1")) {

                        fbFs.collection("individual_chats").document(mySqlUserId).collection("lists").document(individualListModel.getMysql_friend_user_id()).update("hide_status", "0");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **more than 200 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: thanks i have reformatted the code to shorten it.. there is lot of boiler plate code and code required.. i have already cut out the variables... not sure if cutting boiler plate will be a good idea...

Comment: Currently what I am doing is passing the ids using an interface (an answer by Frank elsewhere) to retrofit function as map and getting the latest details and updating the firebase values...  the no sql world feels very strange to me..

Comment: now moving to websockets sionara firebase